# Не работает Maven с javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Никак не могу запустить проект со сборкой Maven 
ругается постоянно ошибкой

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x25c0b4fa) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x25c0b4fa
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at yaroslav.khahyda.address.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:121)
    at yaroslav.khahyda.address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:313)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application yaroslav.khahyda.address.MainApp
```

Место где выбивает ошибку

```
public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Загружаем корневой макет из fxml файла.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Отображаем сцену, содержащую корневой макет.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            // Даём контроллеру доступ к главному приложению.
            rootLayoutController = loader.getController();
            rootLayoutController.setMainApp(this);


            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Пытается загрузить последний открытый файл.
        File file = getInfoBotFilePath();
        if (file != null) {
            loadInfoBotFromFile(file);
        }
    }
```

файлы xml переместил в папку resources [image: размещение файлов .xml]

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.MainApp</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

В 6-й строке мы указываем класс который будет запускать наше приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, речь идёт о Java 11+. До 11-й версии все модули, относящиеся к JavaFX шли в комплекте с SDK. Сейчас же требуемые модули и зависимости нужно подключать вручную, например так:

`--add-modules=javafx.controls`

Однако, в этом модуле отсутствует поддержка FXML классов, так что, для FXMLLoader нужно ещё включить сразу и модуль javafx.fxml, то есть, передать в настройки JVM следующую строку:

`--module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

JavaFX раздробили на несколько модулей, так что, стоит посмотреть в [документации](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/), что ещё можно сразу подключить.

*Пример, как добавить настройки в IntelliJ Idea: меню Run -> Edit configurations. В открывшемся окне для нужной конфигурации вставляем VM options.*

Почти то же самое от разработчиков: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx. Успехов

Comment: Как же все усложнили.

Comment: @JaroslavKhahyda это точно. Где можно, стараюсь 8-ку использовать, под внутренние проекты её пока хватает.